# Azure App Service - Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port 6000. WEBSITES_PORT does not work

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I built and deployed a docker image to ACR and App service. I exposed the port in the docker file and set `WEBSITES_PORT` in the application settings. But I kept getting "didn't respond to HTTP pings" error.

In my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 6000
WORKDIR /webapp/
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "server/main.py"]
```

Here are the logs where site startup failed:

```
2022-12-13T19:44:04.647Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container xxxx. Elapsed time = 1651.7761754 sec
2022-12-13T19:44:20.040Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container xxxx. Elapsed time = 1667.1697173 sec
2022-12-13T19:44:22.963Z ERROR - Container xxxx for site yyyy is not running, failing site start
2022-12-13T19:44:22.984Z ERROR - Container xxxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 6000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-12-13T19:44:23.002Z INFO  - Stopping site yyyy because it failed during startup.
/home/LogFiles/2022_12_14_ln1mdlwk000058_default_docker.log  (https://yyyy.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2022_12_14_aaaa_default_docker.log)
2022-12-14T05:32:00.645431054Z [2022-12-14 05:32:00 +0000] [1] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:6000 (CTRL + C to quit)
2022-12-14T05:50:20.981722886Z [2022-12-14 05:50:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Running on http://127.0.0.1:6000 (CTRL + C to quit)
```

Here are the logs where docker runs:

```
2022-12-14T06:33:02.853Z INFO  - Pulling image: cccc.azurecr.io/bbbb:tag
2022-12-14T06:33:03.642Z INFO  - 94 Pulling from bbbb
2022-12-14T06:33:03.643Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:123456
2022-12-14T06:33:03.643Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for cccc.azurecr.io/bbbb:tag
2022-12-14T06:33:03.646Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2022-12-14T06:33:03.656Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2022-12-14T06:33:03.657Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=6000 
--name xxxx_0_d7bfb097 
-e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=cccc.azurecr.io/bbbb:tag
-e PORT=6000 
-e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false 
-e WEBSITES_PORT=6000
-e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxxx
-e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False 
-e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0
-e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=xxxx.azurewebsites.net 
-e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=7210fbf7a062fd0ff739205809c9182b72493680f0a70d46e83abcbde795374a 
-e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 
-e NODE_OPTIONS=--require /agents/node/build/src/Loader.js 
-e JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/agents/java/applicationinsights-agent-codeless.jar
-e StartupBootstrapper=Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StartupBootstrapper 
-e DOTNET_SHARED_STORE=/agents/core/store/lin 
-e DOTNET_ADDITIONAL_DEPS=/agents/core/additionalDeps 
-e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False 
cccc.azurecr.io/bbbb:tag
```

Btw I'm not sure where the variables like `NODE_OPTIONS`, `StartupBootstrapper`, and `DOTNET_SHARED_STORE` come from...

I have gone through the solutions on these posts:

[Docker never runs on Azure - Waiting for response to warmup request for container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723980/docker-never-runs-on-azure-waiting-for-response-to-warmup-request-for-containe)

[[Bug] Azure App Service Container exposes and pings different ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/936935/bug-azure-app-service-container-exposes-and-pings.html) This post does not `-p` flag in `docker run` and it still works.

[Azure web app for container - failed during startup - didn't respond to HTTP pings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169920/azure-web-app-for-container-failed-during-startup-didnt-respond-to-http-pin).

My understanding: it looks like the app already runs in the docker, since it has `Running on http://127.0.0.1:6000`. But the port it's not published to the host machine. The `docker run` command only has `--expose` flag, no `-p`. That's why it keeps telling me `Container xxxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port`. I don’t know why it picked up the exposed port but not published it.

I have tried:

- set PORT = 6000 only
- set WEBSITES_PORT = 6000 only
- set PORT = 6000 + WEBSITES_PORT = 6000
- upgrade app service plan
- SSH into app service. It shows `SSH CONN CLOSE`

But none of them works.

Since I can’t edit `docer run` command, what can I do to fix this?
Is my understanding of the current situation wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! I should set the host to `0.0.0.0`, instead of using the default one `127.0.0.0`.

Another observation: after I deployed the image to app service, it will automatically add an environment variable `PORT` with the value of `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile. Without defining `WEBSITES_PORT`, it somehow works with this command `docker run --expose=6000 -PORT=6000`.